# How are partitons handled in Ubuntu, compared to Windows?

Tags: windows, partitioning

How are partitions in my hard disk handled in Ubuntu? I want to draw parallels with what Windows does.

Let's say I have a HDD formatted as ext4, if I create 2 partitions and mount them at `/data-part` and `/movies`, have I created 2 partitions like `D:/` and `E:/`?

Comment: I've deleted the second question in your post, as we only want one question per post. Feel free to create another question post with your second question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, let's correct a little misconception:

> Let's say I have a HDD formatted as ext4, if I create 2 partitions...

You don't format a hard disk to a file system like ext4 or NTFS or FAT32, you format *partitions* to those file systems. When people say they've formatted a hard disk to ext4, they generally mean they've created a single partition covering the entire disk, and created an ext4 file system for that partition.

---

In **Windows**, partitions are each assigned a different drive letter (`C:`, `D:`, etc). This makes it easier to discover which files are placed in which partitions. A hard disk can have several partitions, and a computer can have several hard disks and other storage devices. The downside is that you can't easily put different directories in different partitions, you can't put `C:\Windows` in one partition and `C:\Users` in other for example, they both must be in the `C:` partition.

In **Linux**, everything is a file, and it is all found under the root directory, `/`. A partition can be mounted to any directory under `/`. For example, you could mount one partition to `/home`, another to `/var`, and another to `/`, which would contain all the other files, but not ones in `home` or `var`.

In Linux, even devices and running processes are files. For example, under `/proc`, you will find all the running processes, and under `/dev/`, all the connected devices. Hard disks are typically named `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sbc`, etc. Partitions with hard disks are typically named `/dev/sda1`: `sda` represents the hard drive, and `1` represents the number of the partition within that hard drive. Every partition is then mounted to a directory in your file system. For example, your CD-ROM drive `/dev/cdrom0` could be mounted to `/media/cdrom0`. In your file explorer, you would navigate to `/media/cdrom0` to see the CD's files.

While this makes conceptually more difficult than Windows' system, it is much more flexible, as you can assign any directory to a new partition.